# output filename and 'found string' on same line in output file

Tags: awk, filenames, output

Semi-newbie. Trying to automate something using an awk script. Should be simple - in theory.

Set of files, all ending in .lst. In each file there is a single line (out of hundreds) with a particular string - say the word 'Wall'. What I hope to do is end up with a file where each line ends up with (i) filename, and (ii) the output string. I have the 'pieces' working separately, but haven't figured out how to put them together (to generate a common output file).

So, suppose I have 3 *.lst files (file1.lst, trash.lst, blah.lst). I can output the filenames into a file using something like the following (no doubt there are better ways, but it works...):

```
      ls -l *.lst | awk '{ print "File: " $9 }' > filenames.dat
```

And, its easy to output the lines containing 'Wall' from each *.lst file to a common file, using something like:

```
 awk '/Wall/{print}'  *.lst > wallvals.dat
```

I can post-process and merge the two together in various ways, but I'd like to figure out how to do it all in one line using awk. So, the resulting output file might look like:

```
 File: file1.lst   Wall data 4.54
 File: trash.lst   Wall data 3.44
 File: blah.lst    Wall data 333.66
```

I've tried a variety of pipe approaches, or nesting various bits within an awk argument - but nothing I've tried has worked (unless the intent is to generate error messages).

Pointers to the obvious appreciated in advance...

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 7):

The filename of the file currently being processed by `awk` is available in the special variable `FILENAME`.  This means that you could adapt your second `awk` command like so:

```bash
awk '/Wall/ { printf "%s:%s\n", FILENAME, $0 }' *.lst
```

or, if you don't like `printf`,

```bash
awk '/Wall/ { print FILENAME ":" $0 }' *.lst
```

or, by making use of the output field separator, `OFS`,

```bash
awk -v OFS=: '/Wall { print FILENAME, $0 }' *.lst
```

This outputs the filename and the line(s) that matches the pattern, with a colon in between.

This is identical to what the following `grep` command does:

```bash
grep -H 'Wall' *.lst
```

... with the tiny difference that the search string here is used as a basic regular expression rather than an extended regular expression (but that does not matter in this case).  The `-H` option is not standard and is unnecessary if `grep` is given more than a single filename. `grep 'Wall' /dev/null *.lst` would be the more standard way of writing the same command (the utility always outputs the filename with each match if given more than one pathname).

If you want the *exact* output format that you mention in the question, then modify the `printf` format string:

```bash
awk '/Wall/ { printf "File: %s\t%s\n", FILENAME, $0 }' *.lst
```

or,

```bash
awk '/Wall/ { print "File: " FILENAME "\t" $0 }' *.lst
```

This outputs the string `File:`  followed by the filename, a tab character, and the line.

Regarding your first command: It is *generally* a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`, partly because it's almost always unnecessary and inelegant, and partly because the output of `ls` is mainly for looking at (the filenames may have extra formatting done to them). It almost always also means you won't be able to read all valid filenames.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)